# Height range of binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I can mathematically prove that the possible heights of a binary tree is:**logN <= Height <=N-1**(N is the number of nodes). However, how do I explain this answer by using just one or two sentences?

Comment: What is Logn and what does n-1 mean in regards to height?

Comment: @progenhard So you mean I need to explain why logN is minimum and why N-1 is maximum value?

Comment: So a tree with one node has a height of 0? That's ... odd. What is the height of an empty tree?

Comment: @JimMischel I am pretty sure the height of empty tree is -1.

Comment: @JimMischel By the way, if you said the tree is empty, that means nothing at all.Which would be invalid to talk about `Tree`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider 2 cases when minimum height and maximum height happens.

Minimum height: When each non-leaf node has exactly two children

Maximum height: When each non-leaf node has exactly one child, i.e. linear

Comment: Upvote you for providing answers much easier than using mathematical proof. Thanks.

Comment: @FlowerFire Actually it may be even easier if you draw a simple graph to explain. For e.g. , to illustrate the case for max. height, you can draw something like `1-2-3-4-5-6-7` to visualize a tree that has a linear structure :)

Comment: Correct. This will be degenerated binary tree, which is the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

A perfectly balanced tree (non-leaf nodes have 2 children) has size N=2^n-1 nodes, log2(N)=n levels.

The degenerate case of a tree (every node has single child) is a list, size N has N levels.

Comment: For the degenerate case, in terms of height, it should be `height = N -1`. But upvote you for providing another answer.